# If $f(a_n)\rightarrow f(L)$ then $a_n\rightarrow L$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $L$ be a real number. Let $f$ be a  function that is continuous at $L$.  I know that if a sequence $a_n\rightarrow L$ then $f(a_n)\rightarrow f(L)$. But is the converse true? I couldn't come up with a counter example. I think this has to be in relation with the fact that $f$ being a bijection or not. Indeed, if $f(a_n)=b_n$ and $f$ is invertible, then $a_n=f^{-1}(b_n)$, and thus we can apply the first conclusion to the sequence $b_n$ in this way: if $f(a_n)\rightarrow f(L)$ which means that 
$b_n\rightarrow f(L)$ then we know since $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $f(L)$
that $f^{-1}(b_n)=a_n\rightarrow f^{-1}(f(L))=L$, but what if $f$ is not invertible, do we still have the result?  Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If $f$ is not bijective, you will not be able to deduce $a_n\rightarrow L$ from $f(a_n)\rightarrow f(L)$.

**Counterexample**: The function $f: x \mapsto 0$ maps any (possibly divergent) series to a constant, and thus convergent series.

Answer (score 0):

Take a non-injective function, such as $f(x) = \sin x$, and let $a_n = 1/n$ and $L = 2\pi$.